# Problem exporting large amounts of data in IE8 with display tag

Tags: java, displaytag

I have an issue where I cannot export a large amount of data (approx 200 rows - not that large really) using displaytag in IE8.

Has anyone encountered this issue?
The same code works perfectly in Firefox

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Please explain "can't export"?

Comment: what "data" are you trying to "export" and what exactly is the problem when you're doing this? are you getting any error-messages?

Comment: What i mean by cant export is the export functionality in DisplayTag will not function

Comment: Im trying to export 2 columns with name and title.. and no im not getting any error messages sadly. I will try and get the source for the displaytag classes and debug through that to see if its any help

Comment: ok i think i found the issue. The max length of a url in IE is 2083 charachters. Firefox allows more that 65000 charachters. I allow the user to search on many userIds at a time (7 charachters in length and comma delimited). DisplayTag builds a url which is too long for IE and hence will not work. My form is using Post but DisplayTag always uses GET when generating the URLS for the export. I guess the next question is, is it possible to use POST for export in displayTag?